# Wait for datastore update before proceeding

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm working on a lightweight app, and I have quite a few situations where the user submits a form, the form data is processed and pushed to the datastore, and then the user is redirected to a page that displays some of the same data. It's quite often the case that the user gets to the page before the datastore has been updated, so they see old data. Is there any way to have the app wait for the datastore to update before proceeding? The obvious hacky solution is calling `sleep(1)`, but that's obviously not ideal and takes longer than the actual update.

Answer (score 3):

Just get the **key** the `.put()` returns:

```
key = mything.put()
```

and pass it on to the other page (e.g via `urlsafe`).  The other page can rebuild the key and then

```
thething = key.get()
```

will **always** give you updated data -- i.e, this (`key.get()`) is one simple way to get strong consistency from the GAE datastore!

Comment: Is there a better way to pass on the key than just loading up the redirect URL with GET parameters?

Comment: You can pass the string representation of a key to your app just like you pass any other data.

Comment: I pass an id instead of a key.