# Wait for datastore changes before redirecting

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935423/wait-for-datastore-update-before-proceeding), except that the answer is not suitable.

I populate a table from a datastore query, then there is a link allowing the user to delete a specific row. Clicking the link goes to a url that deletes the row from the datastore then redirects back to the table.

Changes more often than not aren't shown in the table until reloading again.

Easy solution is to redirect to another page, that uses a javascript redirect to add a delay of a couple of seconds. Other alternative is to send details back to the page like `action=delete&key=###` and then make sure that item is missed from the table. That's a pain though.

Comment: I hate people that provide answer that suggest re-design of the question... but I'll do it anyways :)   Can you instead make an AJAX call to delete the row, and then just remove it from the table in the DOM if the response is successful?

Comment: @NickFranceschina, this is actually for an admin page in this case, so I'd rather have something simple. AJAX is a good solution though, and not too tricky to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is with ancestor queries.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Ancestor_queries

Create the entities with a parent.  When one of the entities is deleted, you can run an ancestor query for your table list view which will have strong consistency when data is changed.

Example ancestor query:

```
tom = Person(key_name='Tom')

photo_query = Photo.all()
photo_query.ancestor(tom)
```

Comment: Not always. Careful when using ancestors on data that commits often.

Answer (score 1):

With the datastore, unless you can use ancestors, you cant guarantee when the indexes will be updated, only the entity itself (for getting by key later) by doing a put without async. Best is a combination of your suggestion where the client takes into account its action to patch the ui, plus maybe using memcache to remember recent actions and patch queries server-side before returning to client.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach.  Use Javascript and AJAX.  When the user clicks a link, you do two things:

1. Use Javascript/jQuery to remove the row from the DOM, and
2. Send an AJAX call to the server to do the appropriate datastore modifications.

It makes for a nice user experience because you are not reloading the page at all.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider that there is always room for displaying outdated info in the table: for example displaying the table simultaneously in 2 different windows/tabs, then in one of them deletion is performed, the other will still display a delete link which will cause a 404 if followed.

With this in mind I'd 1st focus on managing the expectations (the user should know that the page may occasionally display outdated info) and then on the user's ability to get an outdated page in sync (refresh button?). Which *might* make the issue moot.

The delay-based "solutions" are bound to fail sooner or later in race condition scenarios, I wouldn't bother with the extra complexity. Especially for the document where the deletion is done: that's exactly where the user *knows* that the info is outdated (for free) and would be likely inclined to refresh until the recent change becomes visible.